# Rust proper error handling (auto convert from one error type to another with question mark)

Tags: rust

I want to learn how to properly deal with errors in Rust. I have read the [book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html) and [this example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html#examples); now I would like to know how I should deal with errors in this function:

```
fn get_synch_point(&self) -> Result<pv::synch::MeasPeriods, reqwest::Error> {
    let url = self.root.join("/term/pv/synch"); // self.root is url::Url
    let url = match url {
        Ok(url) => url,
        // ** this err here is url::ParseError and can be converted to Error::Kind https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.8.3/src/reqwest/error.rs.html#54-57 **//
        Err(err) => {
            return Err(Error {
                kind: ::std::convert::From::from(err),
                url: url.ok(),
            })
        }
    };

    Ok(reqwest::get(url)?.json()?) //this return reqwest::Error or convert to pv::sych::MeasPeriods automaticly
}
```

This code is improper; it causes a compilation error:

```
error[E0451]: field `kind` of struct `reqwest::Error` is private
  --> src/main.rs:34:42
   |
34 |             Err(err) => return Err(Error{kind: ::std::convert::From::from(err), url: url.ok()})
   |                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ field `kind` is private

error[E0451]: field `url` of struct `reqwest::Error` is private
  --> src/main.rs:34:81
   |
34 |             Err(err) => return Err(Error{kind: ::std::convert::From::from(err), url: url.ok()})
   |                                                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ field `url` is private
```

What is a proper pattern to deal with that case? For me, `reqwest::Error` in this case is a good solution so I would like to avoid defining my own error type:

```
enum MyError {
    Request(reqwest::Error),
    Url(url::ParseError) // this already a part of request::Error::Kind!!!
}
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

### Update 2020

The rust programming language is evolving quickly so a new answer can be added! I really liked [custom_error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53130345/5190508) but now I think [`thiserror`](https://github.com/dtolnay/thiserror) will be my loved one!

```rust
use thiserror::Error;

#[derive(Error, Debug)]
pub enum DataStoreError {
    #[error("data store disconnected")]
    Disconnect(#[from] io::Error),
    #[error("the data for key `{0}` is not available")]
    Redaction(String),
    #[error("invalid header (expected {expected:?}, found {found:?})")]
    InvalidHeader {
        expected: String,
        found: String,
    },
    #[error("unknown data store error")]
    Unknown,
}
```

This allow change `io::Error` to `DataStoreError::Disconnect` with question mark `?`. Go here for [details](https://github.com/dtolnay/thiserror#details)

useful links:

- [**great blog about using `thiserror` in combine with `anyhow`**](https://nick.groenen.me/posts/rust-error-handling/)

---

### Other interesting crates:

- [anyhow](https://crates.io/crates/anyhow) -  Flexible concrete Error type built on std::error::Error
- [snafu](https://crates.io/crates/snafu) - Situation Normal: All Fouled Up - SNAFU is a library to easily assign underlying errors into domain-specific errors while adding context. (similar to thiserror)
- [custom_error](https://crates.io/crates/custom_error) - This crate contains a **macro** that should make it easier to define custom errors without having to write a lot of boilerplate code.

#### for panics:

- [proc-macro-error](https://crates.io/crates/proc-macro-error) - This crate aims to make error reporting in proc-macros simple and easy to use.
- [human-panic](https://crates.io/crates/human-panic) - Panic messages for humans. Handles panics by calling std::panic::set_hook to make errors nice for humans.

Comment: +1 for `thiserror`, but a quick correction: you use the `#[from]` attribute to get automatic conversion with the `?` operator, not `#[source]` (which is implied by `#[from]`)

Comment: those seem like nice libraries, however given that they're libraries, they feel like workarounds, around the "proper" way that the rust language developer intended. What is the purely rustian way (maybe involving the standard library) way to solve this?

Comment: @Nearoo they only get rid of boiler plate that you need add manually to get `std::error::Error` trait satisfied. Error handling is hard and depends on your problem but in my cases the above libs work like a charm!

Answer (score 20):

Unfortunately, in your case you cannot create a `reqwest::Error` from other error types, if the `reqwest` library does not provide a way to do so (and it likely doesn't). To solve this problem, which is very common, especially in applications which use multiple libraries, the proper solution would be one of the following:

1. Declare your own custom enum with all errors your application works with (or one subsystem of your application; granularity highly depends on the project), and declare `From` conversions from all errors you work with to this enum type.

   As an extension of this approach, you can use [`error-chain`](https://crates.io/crates/error-chain) (or [`quick-error`](https://crates.io/crates/quick-error), on which error-chain is basically based) to generate such custom types and conversions in a semi-automatic way.
2. Use a special, generic error type. There are basically two of them:

   a. `Box<Error>` where [`Error`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/error/trait.Error.html) is defined in the standard library.

   b.  Use the [`Error`](https://docs.rs/failure/0.1.1/failure/struct.Error.html) type defined in the [`failure`](https://crates.io/crates/failure) crate.

   Then the question mark operator will be able to convert any compatible error to one of these types because of various `Into` and `From` trait implementations.

Note that the `failure` crate is intended to be *the* way to define errors promoted in the Rust community. Not only does it provide a common error type and trait (which fixes various issues with the `std::error::Error` trait; see for example [here](https://boats.gitlab.io/blog/post/2017-11-16-announcing-failure/)), it also has facilities to define your own error types (for example, with [`failure_derive`](https://crates.io/crates/failure_derive)), and for tracking error context, causes and generating backtrace. Additionally, it tries to be as compatible with the existing error handling approaches as possible, therefore it can be used to integrate with libraries which use other, older approaches (`std::error::Error`, `error-chain`, `quick-error`) quite easily. So I strongly suggest you to consider using this crate first, before other options.

I have already started using `failure` in my application projects, and I just can't express how much easier and nicer error handling has become. My approach is as follows:

1. Define the `Result` type:

   ```
   type Result<T> = std::result::Result<T, failure::Error>;
   ```
2. Use `Result<Something>` everywhere where an error can be returned, using the question mark operator (`?`) to convert between errors and functions like [`err_msg`](https://docs.rs/failure/0.1.1/failure/fn.err_msg.html) or [`format_err!`](https://docs.rs/failure/0.1.1/failure/macro.format_err.html) or [`bail!`](https://docs.rs/failure/0.1.1/failure/macro.bail.html) to create my own error messages.

I have yet to write a library using `failure`, but I imagine that for libraries it would be important to create more specific errors declared as an enum, which can be done with the `failure_derive` crate. For applications, though, the `failure::Error` type is more than enough.

Comment: This is most upvoted but failure and error-chain adding additional complex and not standard traits. Nowadays there are crates that work with just standard rust error handling for example: [custom_error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53130345/5190508) and [thiserror](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58337971/5190508). Could you also include them here?

Comment: the failure crate has been deprecated https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/failure/pull/347

Answer (score 5):

In that case, reusing the underlying error type is not possible because you cannot construct its hidden fields. And even when it is possible, I would advise against it, in order to make your code more flexible and future-proof.

Defining custom error types can involve writing a lot of boilerplate, but fortunately several libraries exist to alleviate this pain. *failure*, *error-chain* and *quick-error* were already mentioned above, but I would like to point you to a crate I wrote that involves even less boilerplate than the others : [**custom_error**](https://crates.io/crates/custom_error). With it, you can write:

```
#[macro_use] extern crate custom_error;

custom_error!{ MyError
    Request{source: reqwest::Error} = "request error",
    Url{source: url::ParseError}    = "invalid url"
}
```

Comment: Oo. Thanks for that crate. I first use failure but now I would like just use standard trait Error and this macro do it super easy way!

Answer (score 1):

As [already stated by 
Vladimir Matveev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48431339/155423), the [failure](https://docs.rs/failure/0.1.1/failure/) crate should be your starting point. Here is my solution:

```
use std::io;
use std::result;

use failure::{Backtrace, Fail};

/// This is a new error type manged by Oxide library.
/// The custom derive for Fail derives an impl of both Fail and Display.
#[derive(Debug, Fail)]
pub enum OxideError {
    #[fail(display = "{}", message)]
    GeneralError { message: String },

    #[fail(display = "{}", message)]
    IoError {
        message: String,
        backtrace: Backtrace,
        #[cause]
        cause: io::Error,
    },
}

/// Create general error
pub fn general(fault: &str) -> OxideError {
    OxideError::GeneralError {
        message: String::from(fault),
    }
}

/// Create I/O error with cause and backtrace
pub fn io(fault: &str, error: io::Error) -> OxideError {
    OxideError::IoError {
        message: String::from(fault),
        backtrace: Backtrace::new(),
        cause: error,
    }
}
```

This error enumeration is extendible which allows it to accommodate future modifications that might be made to the program.

Comment: 'failure' has been deprecated. 'anyhow' (easier) and 'thiserror' (more precise, like for libraries) are preferred modern alternatives. Both are by the same author and can be used together.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the `anyhow` crate is good excepts for not supporting `Box<dyn StdError>`.

Most error types implemented Display trait, so use this magic.

1. Customize an error
2. Implement From trait from all object that implements Display

```rust
pub struct MyError {
    pub code: i32,
    pub message: String,
}

impl<E: Display> From<E> for MyError {
    fn from(value: E) -> Self {
        MyError {
            code: 0,
            message: value.to_string(),
        }
    }
}

async fn hello() -> std::result::Result<(), &'static str> {
    return Err("Hello world");
}

async fn test() -> std::result::Result<(), MyError> {
    // &str
    hello().await?;
    // std::io::Error
    std::fs::read("DD")?;
    // serde_json::Error
    let data = serde_json::from_str("[1,2,3]")?;
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: `anyhow` is designed to be used for application (binaries) to handle all errors easily. But it's not good for libraries where you should use `thiserror`. Both crates are created by the same author