# Rust: Implement trait "From" for associated type (Error)

Tags: rust, traits

This is a follow-up question on my previous question: [Rust: Read and map lines from stdin and handling different error types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59187274/rust-read-and-map-lines-from-stdin-and-handling-different-error-types)

I have created the following struct and function to read lines from stdin and parse them into integers and it works:

```rust
use std::io::BufRead;
use std::{io, num, str};

#[derive(Debug)]
enum InputError {
    IOError(io::Error),
    ParseIntError(num::ParseIntError),
}

impl From<io::Error> for InputError {
    fn from(e: io::Error) -> InputError {
        return InputError::IOError(e);
    }
}

impl From<num::ParseIntError> for InputError {
    fn from(e: num::ParseIntError) -> InputError {
        return InputError::ParseIntError(e);
    }
}

pub fn get_integer_lines<T>() -> Result<Vec<T>, InputError>
where
    T: str::FromStr,
{
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    let my_values: Result<Vec<_>, InputError> = stdin
        .lock()
        .lines()
        .map(|line| -> Result<T, InputError> { Ok(line?.parse::<T>()?) })
        .collect();
    my_values
}
```

Now, I thought that I would replace `u32` for a type parameter T to allow for any kind of numeric type. To do this I assume that I need to restrict T to types implementing the FromStr trait and then somehow implement the From trait to allow conversion from FromStr::Err into my "InputError".

Following the error I first got

```
error[E0277]: `?` couldn't convert the error to `InputError`
  --> src/lib.rs:30:69
   |
30 |         .map(|line| -> Result<T, InputError> { Ok(line?.parse::<T>()?) })
   |                                                                     ^ the trait `std::convert::From<<T as std::str::FromStr>::Err>` is not implemented for `InputError`
   |
   = note: the question mark operation (`?`) implicitly performs a conversion on the error value using the `From` trait
   = help: consider adding a `where InputError: std::convert::From<<T as std::str::FromStr>::Err>` bound
   = note: required by `std::convert::From::from`
```

I tried something like this:

```
impl std::convert::From<<T as std::str::FromStr>::Err> for InputError {
    fn from(e: <T as std::str::FromStr>::Err) -> InputError {
        return InputError::ParseIntError(e)
    }
}
```

But that instead results in:

```
error[E0412]: cannot find type `T` in this scope
  --> src/lib.rs:22:26
   |
22 | impl std::convert::From<<T as std::str::FromStr>::Err> for InputError {
   |                          ^ not found in this scope
```

So basically what I want to express is something along the lines of:
"I want to implement the trait `From<T::Err>` for my `InputError` for every `T` which also implements `FromStr`. Is this even possible and if so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So basically what I want to express is something along the lines of:
>   "I want to implement the trait `From<T::Err>` for my `InputError` for every `T` which also implements `FromStr`. Is this even possible and if so, how?

This isn't what the error is saying.

The trait `FromStr` has an associated type, `Err`. The error is saying that this associated error type cannot be converted to `InputError`.

First, let's simplify by getting rid of the type parameters:

```
fn get_integer_lines() -> Result<Vec<u32>, InputError> {
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    let my_values = stdin
        .lock()
        .lines()
        .map(|line| Ok(line?.parse()?))
        .collect();
    my_values
}
```

This works!

The associated `Err` type for `u32`'s `FromStr` implementation is `ParseIntError` and you have correctly implemented `From<ParseIntError> for InputError`.

The reason this doesn't work for `T` is because `T`'s `FromStr::Err` type *could* be anything. By using a type parameter, you are telling the compiler that you expect this function to work for *any possible* type `T`, but it only works for types where  `FromStr::Err` can be converted to your `InputError` type.

The error message gives you a hint:

```
= help: consider adding a `where InputError: std::convert::From<<T as std::str::FromStr>::Err>` bound
```

So let's do that:

```
fn get_integer_lines<T>() -> Result<Vec<T>, InputError>
where
    T: str::FromStr,
    InputError: From<<T as str::FromStr>::Err>,
{
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    let my_values = stdin
        .lock()
        .lines()
        .map(|line| Ok(line?.parse()?))
        .collect();
    my_values
}
```

This tells the compiler that you expect the function to work for all possible `T` *provided that*:

- `T` implements `FromStr` and,
- the associated `Err` type from `T`'s `FromStr` implementation can be converted into an `InputError`