# How to implement From for an associated type?

Tags: rust, type-conversion

I have the following trait for which I provide multiple implementations:

```
pub trait Readable {
    type Error;
    fn read_u8(&mut self) -> Result<u8, Self::Error>;
}
```

I provide an error type that can return an error from the associated type of the above trait:

```
pub enum MyError<R>
where R: Readable,
{
    Readable(R::Error),
    Unknown(&'static str),
}
```

I want to implement `From` for the above:

```
impl<R> From<R::Error> for MyError<R>
where R: Readable,
{
    fn from(e: R::Error) -> Self {
        Self::Readable(e)
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b01744f00f1e54de158e0da672289ada)

This gives me an error:

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `std::convert::From<MyError<_>>` for type `MyError<_>`:
  --> src/lib.rs:14:1
   |
14 | / impl<R> From<R::Error> for MyError<R>
15 | | where R: Readable,
16 | | {
17 | |     fn from(e: R::Error) -> Self {
18 | |         Self::Readable(e)
19 | |     }
20 | | }
   | |_^
   |
   = note: conflicting implementation in crate `core`:
           - impl<T> From<T> for T;
```

I'm confused by this error. One problem I can see is that multiple implementations of `Readable` may have the same `Error` associated type, but then I would expect the error to indicate an ambiguity, not that I'm trying to implement `impl<R> From<R> for R` when I'm not.

Why would it think that's what I'm trying to do, and how to convince the compiler to implement `From` for the `Error` associated type?

---

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59214210/rust-implement-trait-from-for-associated-type-error) asks a similar question but does not seem to apply to my scenario.

Answer (score 2):

> Why would it think that's what I'm trying to do, and how to convince the compiler to implement `From` for the `Error` associated type?

You can't. The problem is that anything can implement `Readable`, and thus you could have a `Readable::Error = MyError`, which would overlap with the blanket implementation the compiler is telling you about (where any `T` can be converted to itself).

Rust doesn't currently allow overlapping trait implementations at all. I'm not even sure specialisation would allow for it, and anyway it's nowhere near completion.