# How do I convert a reqwest stream into an actix stream?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio, actix-web

I'm trying to convert a stream from reqwest into an actix response's stream to avoid creating a large `Vec` in memory:

```
use actix_web::{web, HttpRequest, HttpResponse, Responder};

pub async fn test(
    req: HttpRequest
) -> impl Responder {
    let request = reqwest::get("https://www.rust-lang.org").await;
    if request.is_err() {
        println!("Error: {:?}", request.err());
    }
    let request = request.unwrap();
    let stream = request.bytes_stream();

    HttpResponse::Ok()
        .content_type("text/html")
        .streaming(stream)
}
```

The compiler is giving me:

```
  --> src/routes/test.rs:97:10
   |
97 |         .streaming(stream)
   |          ^^^^^^^^^ the trait `actix_http::error::ResponseError` is not implemented for `reqwest::error::Error`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::convert::From<reqwest::error::Error>` for `actix_http::error::Error`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::convert::Into<actix_http::error::Error>` for `reqwest::error::Error`
```

I've tried all I could without luck:

- creating a pass-through `Stream` (not even compiling, I'm not good at converting types)
- implementing the missing error for Reqwest error (that error is not public so I couldn't do that)
- trying anyhow (but not sure if I use it right)

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: Your question might be answered by the answers of [Rust proper error handling (auto convert from one error type to another with question mark)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48430836/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: Will take a look at both answer, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a thin layer to link the two systems, transferring the error types:
https://github.com/clia/reqwest-actix-stream