# How can I convert a Result<T, E1> to Result<T, E2> when the question mark operator is ineffective?

Tags: error-handling, rust

Is there an idiomatic/concise way to convert `Result<T, E1>` to `Result<T, E2>` when `E2` has implemented the `From` trait for `E1`?

I cannot use the `?` operator because it doesn't compile.

In my case, `E1` is `ParseIntError`, and `E2` is a custom `CalcPackageSizeError` error enum.

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=347003ed36a19b6c2ba2b0323bdbaa57)

```rust
use std::error;
use std::fmt;
use std::io;
use std::io::Read;
use std::num::ParseIntError;

#[derive(Debug)]
enum CalcPackageSizeError {
    InvalidInput(&'static str),
    BadNum(&'static str),
}
impl error::Error for CalcPackageSizeError {}
impl fmt::Display for CalcPackageSizeError {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(
            f,
            "{}",
            match *self {
                Self::InvalidInput(err_desc) => err_desc,
                Self::BadNum(err_desc) => err_desc,
            }
        )
    }
}

impl From<ParseIntError> for CalcPackageSizeError {
    fn from(_: ParseIntError) -> Self {
        CalcPackageSizeError::BadNum(
            "Error in calculating size of one or more of the packages involved.",
        )
    }
}

fn parse_comma_separated_num(num_str: &str) -> Result<usize, ParseIntError> {
    num_str
        .chars()
        .filter(|char| *char != ',')
        .collect::<String>()
        .parse::<usize>()
}

fn calc_all_package_size(contents: &str) -> Result<usize, CalcPackageSizeError> {
    contents
        .split('\n')
        .skip(2)
        .map(|package_str| {
            let amount_str = package_str
                .split(' ')
                .filter(|element| *element != "")
                .nth(1);

            if let Some(amt_str) = amount_str {
                parse_comma_separated_num(amt_str)?
                // match parse_comma_separated_num(amt_str) {
                //     Ok(amt) => Ok(amt),
                //     Err(err) => Err(From::from(err)),
                // }
            } else {
                Err(CalcPackageSizeError::InvalidInput("Input not as expected, expected the 2nd spaces-delimited item to be the size (integer)."))
            }
        })
        .sum()
}

fn main() {
    let mut wajig_input = String::from(
        "Package                           Size (KB)        Status
=================================-==========-============
geoip-database                      10,015      installed
aptitude-common                     10,099      installed
ieee-data                           10,137      installed
hplip-data                          10,195      installed
librsvg2-2                          10,412      installed
fonts-noto-color-emoji              10,610      installed",
    );
    // io::stdin().read_to_string(&mut wajig_input).expect("stdin io rarely fails.");
    match calc_all_package_size(wajig_input.as_str()) {
        Ok(total_size_in_kb) => {
            let size_in_mb = total_size_in_kb as f64 / 1024.0;
            println!("Total size of packages installed: {} MB", size_in_mb);
        }
        Err(error) => {
            println!("Oops! Encountered some error while calculating packages' size.");
            println!("Here's the error: \n {}", error);
            println!("\n-- Gracefully exiting..");
        }
    }
}
```

This gives a compile error:

```
error[E0308]: `if` and `else` have incompatible types
  --> src/main.rs:59:17
   |
52 | /             if let Some(amt_str) = amount_str {
53 | |                 parse_comma_separated_num(amt_str)?
   | |                 ----------------------------------- expected because of this
54 | |                 // match parse_comma_separated_num(amt_str) {
55 | |                 //     Ok(amt) => Ok(amt),
...  |
59 | |                 Err(CalcPackageSizeError::InvalidInput("Input not as expected, expected the 2nd spaces-delimited item to be the size (integer)."))
   | |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `usize`, found enum `Result`
60 | |             }
   | |_____________- `if` and `else` have incompatible types
   |
   = note: expected type `usize`
              found enum `Result<_, CalcPackageSizeError>`
note: return type inferred to be `usize` here
  --> src/main.rs:53:17
   |
53 |                 parse_comma_separated_num(amt_str)?
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Though both errors seem semantically similar, I need to respond in different way to both the situations, so I can't make them one.

Comment: Either you implement `From<E1> for E2`  or use `Result::map_err`

Comment: @Netwave I have implemented `From` for my error type.  I'll look into the Result::map_err though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234447/discussion-between-vivek-yadav-and-shepmaster).

Comment: `Ok(parse_comma_separated_num(amt_str)?)` or `parse_comma_separated_num(amt_str).map_err(|e| e.into())` should do it.

Comment: @Jmb Thanks! You can write it as an answer rather than a comment so I can accept it!

Comment: @Jmb and I'd be happy to remove the `Ok(x?)` version from my answer if you do. I was already writing the `map_err` version when you commented though ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a combination of [`Result::map_err`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.map_err) and [`Into::into`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html#tymethod.into):

```rust
if let Some(amt_str) = amount_str {
    parse_comma_separated_num(amt_str).map_err(Into::into)
} else {
    Err(CalcPackageSizeError::InvalidInput("Input not as expected, expected the 2nd spaces-delimited item to be the size (integer)."))
}
```

As [Jmb points out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68226375/how-can-i-convert-a-resultt-e1-to-resultt-e2-when-the-question-mark-operat/68227089#comment120581948_68226375), you could also use `Ok` and `?` together:

```rust
if let Some(amt_str) = amount_str {
    Ok(parse_comma_separated_num(amt_str)?)
} else {
    Err(CalcPackageSizeError::InvalidInput("Input not as expected, expected the 2nd spaces-delimited item to be the size (integer)."))
}
```

---

The problem is that `?` **unwraps the value on success** and returns from the function on failure. That means that `parse_comma_separated_num(amt_str)?` evaluates to a `usize`, as the compiler tells you:

> return type inferred to be `usize` here

This would cause the first block to evaluate to a `usize` and the second block to evaluate to a `Result`. Those aren't the same type, resulting in the error you got.

Converting the error type using `map_err` preserves the value as a `Result`, allowing both blocks to evaluate to the same type.

See also:

- [Rust proper error handling (auto convert from one error type to another with question mark)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48430836/155423)

Comment: Holy W, I completely forgot `.into()` existed for errors there. Thanks!